# Faye Client for ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, publish-subscribe, faye

I'm looking for a pub/sub messaging system to connect various applications I'm building, some of them will be iOS, other ones AIR/AS3 and maybe some openFrameworks.

I found out [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com) and it looks like really interesting. I've found libraries to integrate it in all my apps/languages, so I'm trying it out.

Now, the problems are with the AS3 implementation. I've found [this great library](https://github.com/curi1119/faye-client-as) and it's kind of working, BUT I've some issues I can't understand. My main problem is that I can build clients, connect them to a node.js server and exchange information between them, but after a while they stop receiving information.

So I was wondering:

- do anyone of you have experience with Faye and this library, and knows if this behaviour it's normal and if there's a way to prevent it? I've done some tests using some html browser clients and everything was ok, so it's definitely a flash library problem
- do you know any other library to implement Faye in AS3/AIR? I was browsing a lot but I couldn't find anyone
- Do you know any alternative pub/sub messaging system I could implement (easily) in as3?

Thank you

Comment: When creating a FayeClient are you passing any parameters? Maybe you need to increase the connection timeout, or the number of retries to connect to the server. EDIT: You could also use WireShark to analyze the requests and responses between the server and the client and see how the probleme occurs. Maybe there's an error thrown by the server or the client.

Comment: Great suggestions @CristinaGeorgescu, especially WireShark debugging. Perhaps it might be worth trying to narrow down the problem source: the server or the client. I haven't used Faye, but from what I see they have a js client as well. Try to replicate your scenario with js instead of as3. If it fails in the same way, it might be the server. If it doesn't, it's the as3 wrapper. If this is the case,a hacky workaround temporarily would be using the js client from as3 via [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza thank you for your suggestions, I've done some html test and the problem it's definitely the as3 library, I've edited my question accordingly to narrow down the problem

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu I'm not passing any parameters. As long as I can see, the server it's not throwing any error, but the client is disconnecting and reconnecting constantly. Sometimes, after an automatic reconnection, it's ID becomes null

Answer (score -1):

We've open sourced our implementation of AS3 Faye client recently. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ProductMadness/as3-faye-client).

It's been in prod for more than a year and was tested by millions of users, without issues so far. It's used in Flash Player Web and AIR Mobile applications.

Interfaces mimic JS client interfaces, so its setup is as easy as JS client setup. Plus one additional feature: multiple urls for reconnection fallbacks.

Give it a try!